# Grouping rows based on some logic?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

Here is my table structure:

```
// reputations
+----+-------+---------------+
| id | value |   date_time   |
+----+-------+---------------+
| 1  | 5     | 1472105459    | -- in last month
| 2  | -2    | 1472105460    | -- in last month
| 3  | 15    | 1472746410    | -- in last week
| 4  | 5     | 1472746421    | -- in last week
| 5  | 10    | 1472746432    | -- in last week
| 6  | -6    | 1473115566    | -- yesterday
| 7  | 2     | 1473205567    | -- today
| 8  | 10    | 1473205590    | -- today
+----+-------+---------------+
```

I need to **sum** `value` column and group them based on these logic:

```
(CASE WHEN FROM_UNIXTIME(MAX(date_time)) >= CURDATE() THEN 'today'
      WHEN FROM_UNIXTIME(MAX(date_time)) >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) THEN 'yesterday'
      WHEN FROM_UNIXTIME(MAX(date_time)) >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) THEN 'in last week'
      ELSE 'in last month'
END) as range_day
```

So this is expected results:

```
+----+-------+---------------+
| id | value |   date_time   |
+----+-------+---------------+
| 2  | 3     | 1472105460    | -- in last month
| 5  | 30    | 1472746432    | -- in last week
| 6  | -6    | 1473115566    | -- yesterday
| 8  | 12    | 1473205590    | -- today
+----+-------+---------------+
```

Ok well, how can I do that?

---

### EDIT:

I think I didn't ask my question correctly. Let me ask it the other way:
Here is my table structure:

```
// votes
+----+-------+-----------+---------------+
| id | value |  post_id  |   date_time   |
+----+-------+-----------+---------------+
| 1  | 5     | 1         | 1472105459    | -- in last month
| 2  | -2    | 2         | 1472105460    | -- in last month
| 3  | 10    | 2         | 1472746410    | -- in last week
| 4  | 5     | 1         | 1472746421    | -- in last week
| 5  | 10    | 3         | 1472746432    | -- in last week
| 6  | 5     | 1         | 1473115566    | -- in last week
| 7  | -2    | 1         | 1473205567    | -- yesterday
| 8  | 10    | 1         | 1473205590    | -- yesterday
+----+-------+-----------+---------------+
```

I want this output:

```
// votes
+----+-------+-----------+---------------+---------------+
| id | value |  post_id  |   date_time   |   range_day   |
+----+-------+-----------+---------------+---------------+
| 1  | 5     | 1         | 1472105459    | in last month |
| 2  | -2    | 2         | 1472105460    | in last month |
| 3  | 10    | 2         | 1472746410    | in last week  |
| 5  | 10    | 3         | 1472746432    | in last week  |
| 6  | 10    | 1         | 1473115566    | in last week  |
| 8  | 8     | 1         | 1473205590    | yesterday     |
+----+-------+-----------+---------------+---------------+
```

As you see, I have grouped them based on both `post_id` and `range_day`. Noted that I need to keep the biggest `date_time` when some rows merges.

How can I do that?

Comment: `group by range_day`?

Comment: I cannot use `range_day` on `GROUP BY` clause. Actually `range_day` is a alias for the calculated column. So, it can't be used in `GROUP BY`.

Comment: because it's not one of the output column?

Comment: @Fabricator Yup . . . !

Comment: use case expression (copy) in group by

Comment: then just use the actual computation in the group by. group by accepts expressions just like select

Comment: also, you could wrap your query into sub-query and group by range_day

Comment: You dont have a value of 3 where did you get that?where did you get all of your result value?

Comment: @reds `5 - 2 = 3`

Comment: 5 is from the first row?

Comment: @reds Yes .. both `5` and `-2` are in the same group *(`in last month`)*. So I need to sum them.

Comment: the group that you mean is a column or not, i mean if exist like lastmonth last week and so on?

Comment: you have an invalid input of datetime

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have overcomplicated that. Just get rid of `MAX()` in you CASE statement. Then you can GROUP BY `range_day`.

```
SELECT MAX(id) as id,
  SUM(value) as value,
  (CASE WHEN FROM_UNIXTIME(date_time) >= CURDATE() THEN 'today'
        WHEN FROM_UNIXTIME(date_time) >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) THEN 'yesterday'
        WHEN FROM_UNIXTIME(date_time) >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) THEN 'in last week'
        ELSE 'in last month'
  END) as range_day
FROM reputations
GROUP BY range_day
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/39e58c/1

Right now SQLFidde returns this:

```
| id | value |     range_day |
|----|-------|---------------|
|  2 |     3 | in last month |
|  6 |    24 |  in last week |
|  8 |    12 |     yesterday |
```

That is not equal to your expected result. But that's because time is not a constant. Tomorow you will get another result.

**Update:**

You are trying to explain your issue using a not working and not reasonable code. But looking at your expected result, i think you want to group by specific date ranges. So let's first convert your table:

```
SELECT id,
  value,
  DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(date_time)) as dt,
  CURDATE() as today,
  (CASE WHEN FROM_UNIXTIME(date_time) >= CURDATE() THEN 'today'
        WHEN FROM_UNIXTIME(date_time) >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) THEN 'yesterday'
        WHEN FROM_UNIXTIME(date_time) >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) THEN 'in last week'
        ELSE 'in last month'
  END) as range_day
FROM reputations

| id | value |                 dt |              today |     range_day |
|----|-------|--------------------|--------------------|---------------|
|  1 |     5 |    August, 25 2016 | September, 07 2016 | in last month |
|  2 |    -2 |    August, 25 2016 | September, 07 2016 | in last month |
|  3 |    15 | September, 01 2016 | September, 07 2016 |  in last week |
|  4 |     5 | September, 01 2016 | September, 07 2016 |  in last week |
|  5 |    10 | September, 01 2016 | September, 07 2016 |  in last week |
|  6 |    -6 | September, 05 2016 | September, 07 2016 |  in last week |
|  7 |     2 | September, 06 2016 | September, 07 2016 |     yesterday |
|  8 |    10 | September, 06 2016 | September, 07 2016 |     yesterday |
```

Now let's group the result by "hand":

- Group "**yesterday**" has ids 8,7 and valaues 2,10 => max(id) = max(7,8) = **8** and sum(value) = sum(2,10) = **12**
- Group "**in last week**" has ids 3,4,5,6 and valaues 15,5,10,-6 => max(id) = max(3,4,5,6) = **6** and sum(value) = sum(15,5,10,-6) = **24**
- Group "**in last month**" has ids 1,2 and valaues 5,-2 => max(id) = max(1,2) = **2** and sum(value) = sum(5,-2) = **3**

If you want the "biggest date_time" for each group, just add `FROM_UNIXTIME((MAX(date_time))` to your SELECT clause.

**Update 2:**

Just realised the `date_time` column in your expected result. So this is how you get it:

```
SELECT MAX(id) as id,
  SUM(value) as value,
  MAX(date_time) as date_time
FROM reputations
GROUP BY 
  CASE WHEN FROM_UNIXTIME(date_time) >= CURDATE() THEN 'today'
        WHEN FROM_UNIXTIME(date_time) >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) THEN 'yesterday'
        WHEN FROM_UNIXTIME(date_time) >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) THEN 'in last week'
        ELSE 'in last month'
  END
ORDER BY id
```

**Update 3**

This should solve your updated question:

```
SELECT
  MAX(id) as id,
  SUM(value) as value,
  post_id,
  MAX(date_time) as date_time,
  (CASE WHEN FROM_UNIXTIME(date_time) >= CURDATE() THEN 'today'
        WHEN FROM_UNIXTIME(date_time) >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) THEN 'yesterday'
        WHEN FROM_UNIXTIME(date_time) >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) THEN 'in last week'
        ELSE 'in last month'
  END) as range_day
FROM votes
GROUP BY post_id, range_day
ORDER BY id
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/060b5/11

Comment: Well I cannot to get rid of `MAX()` in CASE statement, Because I need to use the biggest *date_time* when some rows merge.

Comment: @stack . . . This syntax should work in MySQL (and Postgres).

Comment: @GordonLinoff Look, I need to use the biggest date_time in CASE statement. So I cannot remove `MAX()`.

Comment: Oh .. thanks for the your update. now I understand my question isn't what I exactly want.

Comment: Well.. here's an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/39e58c/18) wich returns your expected result, wehen you replace `CURRDATE()` with fixed `'2016-09-06'`.

Comment: I've edited the question, if you have some free time, please take a look at it.

Comment: Just because it's you :-) - but that ist the last one.

Comment: Well thank you .. Odd .. you don't use `MAX()` in CASE statement and it works as expected .. I don't know why I think I have to use `MAX()` into CASE statement.

Comment: Just as a note, you have to write `SUM(value)` instead of `MAX(value)` in your third edition.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use MAX() in CASE statement. It would return a global max of the field. Basically a single line. Instead you need to group by the range, and select local max:

```
SELECT a.`value`, a.date_time FROM
    (SELECT sum(`value`) as `value`,
    (CASE WHEN FROM_UNIXTIME(date_time) >= CURDATE() THEN 'today'
          WHEN FROM_UNIXTIME(date_time) >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) THEN 'yesterday'
          WHEN FROM_UNIXTIME(date_time) >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) THEN 'in last week'
          ELSE 'in last month'
    END) as range_day, MAX(date_time) as date_time
    FROM reputations
    GROUP BY 2) a
ORDER BY 2 ASC
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6ea19d/1

Comment: I've edited the question, if you have some free time, please take a look at it.

Comment: @stack don't be lazy. I am sure you can work it out from this point. It's just a tiny amend to the query. Besides, changing a question after an answer is accepted is not recommended.